# How to create breadcumb for custom component in Joomla?

Tags: joomla

I have a custom component in which I want to have a breadcumb to help the user navigate the previous page visits. The basic feature in my component is to show our product releases. The workflow is:

1. The user select the Products menu item. A new page is shown that displays the product names.
2. The user select a specific product name. A new page is shown that displays the releases for this product.
3. The user selects a specific product release. A new page is shown with information about this product release. The user can in this page view other products that depends on this release.

I have tried to use the builtin breadcumb function for this:

`$app =& JFactory::getApplication();

$pathway =& $app->getPathway();

$pathway->addItem("$productName", "index.php?option=com_rcs_products&view=product&productName=$productName&Itemid=$Itemid");`

This correctly creates the breadcumb. But it only displays three levels:
Home - RCS Products - FSPA2-1.2

When I navigate to a new release it displays:
Home - RCS Products - IPU2-2.0

I would like it to show:
Home - RCS Products - FSPA2-1.2 - IPU2-2.0

Is this possible?

Comment: in which file / function would I include that code? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @michi: In my case it was in the controller. But I guess you can add this anywhere you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another item to the pathway:

```
$pathway->addItem("$productCategory", "index.php?blabla");
$pathway->addItem("$productName", "index.php?option=com_rcs_products&view=product&productName=$productName&Itemid=$Itemid");
```

Comment: But then I need to somehow remember each users trail on the site. I would like the breadcumb to show the 3 or 4 latest page vists.

Comment: The breadcrumb in Joomla does not work like that Henrik. It does not show the way the user came to the page, but the hierarchy of the current page (i.e. parents). You could store a cookie of the users history and use that to create a custom path for him though.